# Java: Return statement in a decision structure for Payroll class?

Tags: java, if-statement, return

I have to make a class called Payroll and a PayrollDemo class to go along with it.

This is my code so far for the Payroll Class:

```
public class Payroll {
   private double hoursWorked, payRate;

   public Payroll() {
   hoursWorked = 0.0;
   payRate = 0.0;
}

public void setHoursWorked(double hours) {
hoursWorked = hours;
}

public void setPayRate(double rate) {
 payRate = rate;
}

public double getHoursWorked() {
return hoursWorked;
 }

public double getPayRate() {
return payRate;
}

public String calcPay() {
if (hoursWorked <= 40) {
  double grossPay = hoursWorked * payRate;

  System.out.println("Regular Pay\n============\nHours: " + getHoursWorked() + "\nRate: $" + getPayRate() + "Gross Pay = $" + grossPay);

} else if (hoursWorked > 40) {
    double grossPay = (40 * payRate) + ( (hoursWorked - 40) * payRate * 1.5 );

    System.out.println("Pay With Overtime\n=================\nHours: " + getHoursWorked() + "\nRate: $" + getPayRate() + "Regular Pay = $" + (40 * payRate) + "\nOvertime Hours = " + (hoursWorked - 40) + "\nOvertime Pay Rate = $" + (payRate * 1.5) + "Overtime Pay = $" + ( (hoursWorked - 40) * payRate * 1.5 ) + "Gross Pay = $" + grossPay);
 }
}  
}
```

The problem is that I get an error: return statement missing. I tried replacing both Println with a return instead, but that did not work. So I was just wondering how to fix the program.

Comment: "tried replacing both Println with a return instead, but that did not work" because the compiler can't verify that those conditions are exhaustive. Substitute that `else if` with a simple `else` and put those `return`s back.

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca post your answer that's right

Answer (score 3):

You need a default return value. The compiler needs to know that something will get returned no matter what - it doesn't "like" `else if` even though you may know the logic is sound.

However, you could do:

```
if (hoursWorked <= 40) {
  // return something
} else {
  // return something
}
```

or if you want to keep your else-if:

```
if (hoursWorked <= 40) {
  // return something
} else if (hoursWorked > 40) {
  // return something
}

return defaultString;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the error because the method, `calcPay()` is supposed to return a `String` value which you are not returning. I recommend you change the return type to `double` and return `grossPay` itself e.g.

```
public double calcPay() {
    double grossPay = 0;
    if (hoursWorked <= 40) {
        grossPay = hoursWorked * payRate;
        System.out.println("Regular Pay\n============\nHours: " + getHoursWorked() + "\nRate: $" + getPayRate() + "Gross Pay = $" + grossPay);
    } else {
        grossPay = (40 * payRate) + ( (hoursWorked - 40) * payRate * 1.5 );
        System.out.println("Pay With Overtime\n=================\nHours: " + getHoursWorked() + "\nRate: $" + getPayRate() + "Regular Pay = $" + (40 * payRate) + "\nOvertime Hours = " + (hoursWorked - 40) + "\nOvertime Pay Rate = $" + (payRate * 1.5) + "Overtime Pay = $" + ( (hoursWorked - 40) * payRate * 1.5 ) + "Gross Pay = $" + grossPay);
    }
    return grossPay;
}
```

Also, you do not need `else if (hoursWorked > 40)` because if `hoursWorked <= 40` is not `true`, it implicitly means `hoursWorked > 40`.

If you want to just print the things and not assign the value returned from `calcPay` to any variable, simply change the return type to `void` e.g.

```
public void calcPay() {
    double grossPay = 0;
    if (hoursWorked <= 40) {
        grossPay = hoursWorked * payRate;
        System.out.println("Regular Pay\n============\nHours: " + getHoursWorked() + "\nRate: $" + getPayRate() + "Gross Pay = $" + grossPay);
    } else {
        grossPay = (40 * payRate) + ( (hoursWorked - 40) * payRate * 1.5 );
        System.out.println("Pay With Overtime\n=================\nHours: " + getHoursWorked() + "\nRate: $" + getPayRate() + "Regular Pay = $" + (40 * payRate) + "\nOvertime Hours = " + (hoursWorked - 40) + "\nOvertime Pay Rate = $" + (payRate * 1.5) + "Overtime Pay = $" + ( (hoursWorked - 40) * payRate * 1.5 ) + "Gross Pay = $" + grossPay);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because the return type of `calcPay` is a `String`, but you aren't returning anything. You can make any of the following changes:

```
public void calcPay() {
   if (hoursWorked <= 40) {
     double grossPay = hoursWorked * payRate;

     System.out.println("Regular Pay\n============\nHours: " + getHoursWorked() + "\nRate: $" + getPayRate() + "Gross Pay = $" + grossPay);

   } else{
       double grossPay = (40 * payRate) + ( (hoursWorked - 40) * payRate * 1.5 );

       System.out.println("Pay With Overtime\n=================\nHours: " + getHoursWorked() + "\nRate: $" + getPayRate() + "Regular Pay = $" + (40 * payRate) + "\nOvertime Hours = " + (hoursWorked - 40) + "\nOvertime Pay Rate = $" + (payRate * 1.5) + "Overtime Pay = $" + ( (hoursWorked - 40) * payRate * 1.5 ) + "Gross Pay = $" + grossPay);
   }
}
```

or

```
public String calcPay() {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    if (hoursWorked <= 40) {
        double grossPay = hoursWorked * payRate;

        stringBuilder.append("Regular Pay\n============\nHours: " + getHoursWorked() + "\nRate: $" + getPayRate() + "Gross Pay = $" + grossPay);

    } else{
        double grossPay = (40 * payRate) + ( (hoursWorked - 40) * payRate * 1.5 );

        stringBuilder.append("Pay With Overtime\n=================\nHours: " + getHoursWorked() + "\nRate: $" + getPayRate() + "Regular Pay = $" + (40 * payRate) + "\nOvertime Hours = " + (hoursWorked - 40) + "\nOvertime Pay Rate = $" + (payRate * 1.5) + "Overtime Pay = $" + ( (hoursWorked - 40) * payRate * 1.5 ) + "Gross Pay = $" + grossPay);

    }

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```